# Why is it necessary to add 270 degrees to correct rotation?

Tags: javascript, trigonometry, angle, vector-graphics, game-development

Computing the angle between two points seems inconsistent with regards to DOM rotation

I've written code to compute the angle between two points.  I use the HTML canvas to plot a line between points and I also display a DOM element featuring an arrow character which I rotate to indicate the direction of the vector.  I'm unclear why it's necessary to add 270 degrees to correct the position of the arrow.

See this line below: `radians += (3 * Math.PI / 2); // why 270 degrees?`

```
class Vector {
  constructor(x=0, y=0) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
  }  
  angleFromVectors(anchor, point) {
    return Math.atan2(anchor.y - point.y, anchor.x - point.x);
  }  
  draw(v1, v2) {
    let canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
    if (canvas.getContext) {
      let ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');      
      ctx.moveTo(v1.x, v1.y);
      ctx.lineTo(v2.x, v2.y)
      ctx.stroke();      
    }
  }
  rotateArrow(degrees) {
    let arrow = document.getElementById('arrow');
    arrow.style.webkitTransform = 'rotate('+ degrees + 'deg)'; 
  }
}

let v1 = new Vector(180, 180);
let v2 = new Vector(100, 190);
let vector = new Vector();

let radians = vector.angleFromVectors(v1, v2);
radians += (3 * Math.PI / 2); // why 270 degrees?
let degrees = radians * (180 / Math.PI);

console.log(`radians: ${radians}, degrees: ${degrees}`);
vector.draw(v1, v2);
vector.rotateArrow(degrees);
```

Codepen here: https://codepen.io/cjus/pen/bzKvwO

Comment: because your arrow points up, in JS `0deg` points right and `angleFromVectors` computes the angle in the wrong direction (off by another `180deg`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The arrow is the character `⬆`. Since it points up, if you want it to point left, you need to rotate it. You could also rotate it `-90deg`.

By the way you're actually rotating it `262.875deg`.

Comment: Is it because zero degrees points right? 
https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/9/9a/Degree-Radian_Conversion.svg

Comment: I updated the codepen (https://codepen.io/cjus/pen/bzKvwO) with:
`radians -= 1.570796; // 90 degrees to correct for upfacing arrow`